# Separating list items into columns with single label call

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to separate list items into columns. The only problem is that I don't know how many items will be in the list when it's created (I'm making the list using nltk's tokenizer). How do I put item 1 in column 1, item 2 in column 2, etc. I've put in my simplified code below. Right now puts things in the correct amount of columns, but only the last item in the list in each column. Thanks.

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("This space intentionally left blank")
root.minsize(800,200)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

tokens = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
numtok = len(tokens)
tok = StringVar()
x=0
while x < numtok:
    tok.set(tokens[x])
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=tok).grid(column=x+1, row=2)
    x += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Might not be related to any main issues, but are you purposely wanting that `row=2` hard coded?

Comment: @summea. Yes. It's a relic from the full thing. I already have something I want to be in row 1. For these purposes though, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Does it not do the job?

Comment: @user1462309 Not really it creates the correct number of columns, but the last item from the list is in all of them. I need item 1 in column 1, 2 in column 2, etc. Right now I'm getting item 6 in column 1, 6 in 2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter `Labels` with the `textvariable` set will always update their text if the underlying `StringVar` changes.

You are creating a single `StringVar` which you are updating with each loop causing all labels to have the same text.

Try this instead:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("This space intentionally left blank")
root.minsize(800,200)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

tokens = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
tok_vars = []
for token in tokens:
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(token)
    tok_vars.append(var)

for ii,var in enumerate(tok_vars):
    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=tok_vars[x]).grid(column=ii+1, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Basically just give a different `StringVar`to each `Label`.

Comment: Love the concept, but the code throws the following error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python27/Untitled.py", line 12, in <module>
 tok_vars = [StringVar(str(i)) for i in tokens]
 File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 287, in __init__
 Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 218, in __init__
 self._tk = master.tk
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Any suggestions for fix?